# What is the equivalent of proc format in SAS to python

Tags: python, pandas, format

I want

```
proc format; 
 value RNG

low - 24  = '1'
24< - 35  = '2'
35< - 44  = '3'
44< - high ='4'
```

I need this in python pandas.

Comment: Also how to call this  format.

Comment: can you explain your code a bit more

Comment: What did you try to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for equivalent of the mapping function, you can use something like this.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=5), columns=['score'])

print(df)
```

output:

```
   score
0     73
1     90
2     83
3     40
4     76
```

Now lets apply the binning function for `score` column in dataframe and create new column in the same dataframe.

```
def format_fn(x): 
    if x < 24:
        return '1'
    elif x <35:
        return '2'
    elif x< 44:
        return '3'
    else:
        return '4'

df['binned_score']=df['score'].apply(format_fn)

print(df)
```

output:

```
   score binned_score
0     73            4
1     90            4
2     83            4
3     40            3
4     76            4
```

Comment: In SAS we call macro by RNG.if we want to apply to a varaible we write format A RNG.;Here does that apply

Comment: I am not sure what RNG does in SAS, please add the details in your question. btw, I  have added an example to apply this function for a particular column in a dataframe.